# PeopleSoft Crystal process remains queued if part of PSJob

Tags: crystal-reports, peoplesoft

I am being driven mad with some PeopleSoft jobs that I'm scheduling.  Job Sets and PSJobs with Crystal will not initiate the Crystal processes.  The process (or any other Cyrstal process I try) will run if scheduled independently but in any form of PSJob or Job Set they remain with teh first Crystal job status=queued.

I've spent a day googling, reading Metalink, etc.  Anyone got any ideas?

Cheers
Karl

Comment: For anyone else who encounters this, I managed to get the Crystal, nVision, etc to run on NT by dropping and recreating both Process Schedulers with one one Master Scheduler (on Unix) however then some SQRs would attempt to run on NT.  I updated PS_SCHEDITEM to give them a set server (sorry, don't remember the fields and not at work so can't check).  This appears to be working

Comment: Got the table name wrong - it should be PS_SCHDLITEM and the fields are RUNSERVEROPTION, RUNSERVERNAME

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen when the job is run on a unix process scheduler and, as you probably know, crystal will only run on a windows process scheduler.  The solution was to force the entire job to run on a windows process scheduler.

Comment: I considered this but we have some very data-intensive Cobols and SQRs in the jobs and want them on the Unix Scheduler with no network between the DB and Scheduler.  Doh!

Comment: Do you also have access to the FSCM modules, AM has examples of AE programs scheduling SQR programs.  Insert the data right into the process scheduler tables.  This might be an option as well, instead of crystal being in the PSJOB, replace it with an AE program that submits the crystal to run on windows process scheduler.

Comment: Of course, that is assuming that the crystal does not really have to be part of the job and only has to run at that point in time.  The job would still continue on the unix scheduler, which is where a problem could occur.